# Scanned items (UWP apps) do not appear in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In my application, the items (UWP app package names installed on system) do not appear in the listbox which is inside a user control (AppXPkgPage.cs) that shows up on clicking the respective button "AppX Package Manager".

For detecting installed uwp apps on the system, i have tried:

```
private void AppXPkgPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        String[] Dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps");
        foreach (String Dir in Dirs)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Dir + "\\AppxManifest.xml"))
            {
                UwpApps.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(Dir));
            }

        }

    }
```

UwpApps is the list box. When i change to the page, nothing shows up inside the listbox
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by generating the Form load event properly.